# How to continue PHP script in background without holding up display to the user?

Tags: php, web

Suppose I have some operations (e.g database INSERT queries) that need to be done in the PHP script, but I want to finish displaying the page to the user first before executing them.

One approach I've heard here is using `HTTPResponse::send()` following the display.  What approach is best/fastest here?

**Note/Update**: I'm done displaying everything by the time I'm starting doing these INSERT queries.  This is a static page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ob_implicit_flush(true);`. It will send any data echo'd, immediately to the user's browser.

Comment: and the php function ignore_user_abort(1) may be useful aswell

Comment: Is this preferable to just doing one `flush()` after I'm done displaying?

Comment: This will display stuff as you go, it's the equivalent of adding `flush()` after every echo or print or other display. And yes this goes at the top.

Comment: Won't it be faster to just do one `flush()` when display is done?